# Using Selenium to get Inner span text not working

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following code that's supposed to go through multiple web pages and get email addresses.

```py
for value in data:
        driver.get(value)
        try:
            Email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='email']")
            print(colored(Email.get_attribute('innerHTML'),'green'))    
        except Exception:
            print(colored("No Email found for "+ value, 'red'))
```

This is the html:

```html
<li id="email">
<span class="label">Email</span>
myaddress@Email.com
</li>
```

The issue is that I couldn't get the code to print only `myaddress@Email.com`.
 What gets printed out is `<span class="label">Email</span>myaddress@Email.com`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element contains the text of the child elements as well, you can remove the text of the span

```
email = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
label = email.find_element_by_class_name('label')
text = email.text.replace(label.text, '').strip()
print(colored(text,'green'))
```

Comment: Thank you kindly! it worked, but I just had to change the id to `find_element_by_id('email')`